# how to covert sym function in Matlab to java?

Tags: java, matlab

I have written this function in Matlab :

```
function [ res ] = eqSolve2(t) 
syms y(x) x
y(x)=t;
res=solve(y(x));
end
```

but when I convert it to Java with (deploytool) and run it in java 
it gives me this error message:
"Undefined function 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'."

this is the link for the Code (in java and Matlab)
https://github.com/AbdullahHamdanAldassoukii/proj

how to solve this problem??

Comment: Can you give us the returned java code?

Comment: this link contains the generated jar file https://github.com/AbdullahHamdanAldassoukii/proj